# Boxplot of Multiindex df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn, multi-index

I want to do 2 things:

1. I want to create one boxplot per date/day with all the values for MeanTravelTimeSeconds in that date. The number of MeanTravelTimeSeconds elements varies from date to date (e.g. one day might have a count of 300 values while another, 400).
2. Also, I want to transform the rows in my multiindex series into columns because I don't want the rows to repeat every time. If it stays like this I'd have tens of millions of unnecessary rows.

Here is the resulting series after using df.stack() on a df indexed by date (date is a datetime object index):

```
Date                                        
2016-01-02  NumericIndex                        1611664
            OriginMovementID                       4744
            DestinationMovementID                  5084
            MeanTravelTimeSeconds                  1233
            RangeLowerBoundTravelTimeSeconds        756
                                                 ...   
2020-03-31  DestinationMovementID                  3594
            MeanTravelTimeSeconds                  1778
            RangeLowerBoundTravelTimeSeconds       1601
            RangeUpperBoundTravelTimeSeconds       1973
            DayOfWeek                           Tuesday
Length: 11281655, dtype: object
```

When I use seaborn to plot the boxplot I guet a bucnh of errors after playing with different selections.

If I try to do `df.stack().unstack()` or `df.stack().T` I get then following error:

```
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

How do I plot the boxplot and how do I turn the rows into columns?

Comment: I don't understand how you ended up with a dataframe shaped like this. Could you provide mockup data, in particular check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What I had initially was a normal df with the "automatically generated" numeric index. I had a column called 'Date' where each row was a datetime object and each date was repeated multiple times (repeated for however many times there were values in other columns equivalent to that date). How I got to the dataframe you asked about: What I did afterwards, in order: 1) df.set_index(['Date'])  2) df.stack(). Each of the rows you see were my original columns. I want to have them back as columns, but leave the dates on the left the way they are right now. Having one single date for many values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do need to make your index unique to make the functions you want to work.  I suggest a sequential number that resets at every change in the other two key columns.

```
import datetime as dt
import random
import numpy as np
cat = ["NumericIndex","OriginMovementID","DestinationMovementID","MeanTravelTimeSeconds",
 "RangeLowerBoundTravelTimeSeconds"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
[{"Date":d, "Observation":cat[random.randint(0,len(cat)-1)], 
  "Value":random.randint(1000,10000)} 
 for i in range(random.randint(5,20)) 
 for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2016,1,2), dt.datetime(2016,3,31), freq="14D")])

# starting point....
df = df.sort_values(["Date","Observation"]).set_index(["Date","Observation"])

# generate an array that is sequential within change of key
seq = np.full(df.index.shape, 0)
s=0
p=""
for i, v in enumerate(df.index):
    if i==0 or p!=v: s=0
    else: s+=1
    seq[i] = s
    p=v
df["SeqNo"] = seq
# add to index - now unstack works as required
dfdd = df.set_index(["SeqNo"], append=True)
dfdd.unstack(0).loc["MeanTravelTimeSeconds"].boxplot()
print(dfdd.unstack(1).head().to_string())
```

**output**
[image]

```
                                 Value                                                                                     
Observation      DestinationMovementID MeanTravelTimeSeconds NumericIndex OriginMovementID RangeLowerBoundTravelTimeSeconds
Date       SeqNo                                                                                                           
2016-01-02 0                       NaN                   NaN       2560.0           5324.0                           5085.0
           1                       NaN                   NaN       1066.0           7372.0                              NaN
2016-01-16 0                       NaN                6226.0          NaN           7832.0                              NaN
           1                       NaN                1384.0          NaN           8839.0                              NaN
           2                       NaN                7892.0          NaN              NaN                              NaN
```

Comment: This is amazing, I can't thank you enough. I will read through it carefully tomorrow, but a quick read through already makes me thing this is it. Cheers!